# Отсутствует перевод описания "горячих клавиш"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Отсутствует перевод описания "горячих клавиш":

> Профиль - Править - Параметры - Горячие клавиши:

---

[image: горкнопки]

Comment: Не вижу этого текста в transifex.

Comment: @VladD а я вот думал запросить доступ к transifex, но что-то мало совсем осталось непереведенного :) да и в текущей ситуация, как я понимаю, без модератора всё равно не обойтись.

Comment: Ага, это надо в движке править, судя по всему.