# Сочетание клавиш для разворота блока `Новая активность в %count% вопросе`

Tags: предложение

Может добавить сочетание клавиш для разворота блока `Новая активность в %count% вопросе`? Вот этого:

[image: изображение блока <code>Новая активность в %count% вопросе</code>]

Comment: `F5` не подходит?

Comment: @alexolut после нажатия её порой те вопросы не появляются. как-будто есть разница между тыком в ссылку и обновлением.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский разница безусловно есть, но наиболее актуальные данные будут именно после полного обновления страницы, а не работы AJAX. Также может случиться тормоз, если кликнуть эту строку после большого кол-ва обновлений сообщений.

Comment: А если от верхнего ответа ещё вверх перейти с помощью K,  что будет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а что за K? Есть какие-то сочетания для перехода по вопросам? Я просто про них ничего не знаю)

Comment: @diraria вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3387/181472

Comment: @diraria на основном сайте открывайте профиль, не на Мете.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, переход по K не открывает этот блок, но зато теперь я знаю про горячие клавиши, спасибо!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, зато F делает именно то что я хотел, спасибо!

Comment: @diraria писал с телефона, не было возможности проверить. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует горячая клавиша <kbd>F</kbd> для разворота этого и других похожих блоков:

> [image: список горячих клавиш]

---

Горячие клавиши можно включить в [настройках профиля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences):

`Профиль` → `Править` → `Параметры` → `Горячие клавиши`

> [image: включение/отключение горячих клавиш]

---

На мете и на основном сайте нужно включать отдельно.

Answer (score -1):

Не вижу какого-либо смысла в привязке комбинации клавиш к этому действию. Допустим оно будет, но что дальше? Просто листать страницу и всё равно браться за мышку, когда появится интересный заголовок, чтобы посмотреть его подробнее?

Более того, как я уже высказался в комментарии, обновления, полученные по результатам работы AJAX, будут всё же хуже отражать текущее состояние базы вопросов, нежели после обычного обновления страницы по <kbd>F5</kbd>.

При этом выполнить желаемое действие с клавиатуры можно уже сейчас, достаточно с помощью клавиши <kbd>Tab</kbd> переместить фокус на упомянутый элемент, после чего нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

> [image: Новая активность в фокусе]

Это, конечно, не "горячая кнопка", но эффективно взаимодействовать с сайтом исключительно с помощью клавиатуры вряд ли получится.

Comment: Хорошо, согласен, это бесполезное предложение

Comment: А вот и получится, отличные хоткеи есть на сайте. И не забывайте о слепых и слабовидящих, им мышка вообще бесполезна.