# Горячие клавиши не работают в русской раскладке

Tags: дефект, поддержка

[Горячие клавиши](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5897/227016) не работают в русской раскладке.

(то есть английская <kbd>F</kbd> работает, а русская <kbd>А</kbd> не работает)

Мне кажется стоит это исправить.

[Вроде бы](https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events#%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B), надо всего лишь вешать обработчик не на `keypress`, а на `keydown`.

Вопрос на MSE: [Keyboard shortcuts don't work with a Russian keyboard layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315786/260198).

Comment: Поддерживаю, мне не нравится, что нужно переключаться.

Comment: На MSE задал вопрос: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315786/260198